# How to determine, which one is faster and takes less memory?

Tags: c, performance, memory

**Case 1 :**

```
int fun(int num)
{
    if (num == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return num * fun(num - 1);
}
```

**Case 2:**

```
int fun(int num)
{
    int i = 1;
    do
    {
        i = i * num;
        num--;
    }
    while (num);
    return i;
}
```

I got the above question in interview question and asking about, which one is faster and take less memory. I really don't know, how to find, which one is faster except I was just guessing by just counting the line of code. But, I think, it is not a correct way.
Please anyone help me, what should I consider to solve this type of question.

**UPDATE**

I'm asking for general case not ONLY for the above scenario.

Comment: It might help if you would think about what happens when you call a function. Does anything need to be saved ? Why ? Where ?

Comment: second code is faster because while is fast then function call

Comment: please give proper explanation, so that it will help me for other case too

Comment: You can measure code size with the `size` command on Unix (applied to the object files).  There wouldn't be much difference in the size, though; the code is too simple.  The recursive version will be slower because it uses more function calls and hence more stack space (for the return addresses and function arguments, etc).  It is likely that a faster version still would use a lookup table since you can't represent factorial 13 in a 32-bit int.

Comment: [**Recursion vs. Iteration**](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/info/courses/spring-98/cs211/lecturenotes/07-recursion.pdf) second is [**Which is better RECURSION or ITERATION?**](http://techforum4u.com/entry.php/645-Which-is-better-RECURSION-or-ITERATION)

Comment: Possibly useful note - if you do this with a compiler or programming language that optimises [tail-recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion) (e.g. Prolog I think), the recursive option would be way more promising.

Comment: @Dukeling Except that the function, as written, is not tail-recursive. It must be transformed into a tail-recursive function (either by the programmer or by the compiler) before the tail-call optimization can be applied.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as “too localized”. The two functions compute the same outputs. Within ten years, compilers will be able to generate the same code (the most efficient one) for both functions.

Comment: @PascalCuoq My bad, I made a small (apparently incorrect) assumption there. 10 (hey, probably 20) years ago people probably didn't think we would still use C today, but here we are. Using similar logic to yours 99.9% of the questions on SO needs to be closed (and the other 0.1% probably needs to be migrated to other sites).

Comment: @Dukeling My other comment has nothing to do with whether C was thought to be here for 10 more years ten years ago or with whether C will still be used ten years from now. It has to do with the nature of compilation, an opaque process that transforms source code into object code that computes the same thing. As of now, this question is the only one to be nonsensical in this way on the StackOverflow frontpage. Discussing compilation in abstracto during an interview like it happened to the OP makes no sense at all. Likely a compiler that compiles the two functions to the same code already exists

Comment: @PascalCuoq I was trying to say in 10 years people will still be using compilers / languages more than 10 years old, so it doesn't really matter what the state of compilers / languages is then (and you can't be sure these types of things will be optimised away) (and you can't say that recursion VS iteration is not an important issue). However, I'm sure there are a dozen near-duplicates of this, so closing it as duplicate is another story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the compilers and the optimizations you are using (a good compiler can turn the first code to iterative), but, in general, the second solution will be faster and take less memory (because a recursive call needs to create a stack frame).

Comment: "because a recursive call needs to create a stack frame" although in general yes, but it is usually avoided in tail recursion, where the recursive call substantially boils down to a JMP.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Tail-recursion is similar to iterative when optimized. This is what I meant with "it depends on the compilers [...]".

Comment: Of course, I just wanted to point out that, to give the compiler a good chance to optimize the recursive version to iterative, you have to write it with tail recursion, otherwise things get tricky.

Comment: but let say... there is no while loop and i'm not using recursion. the only difference between two code is line of code (in number). Then ??

Comment: @jWeavers: some lines of code are more expensive than others; some operations are more expensive than others.  Function calls are often more expensive than a simple addition, for example.  Look up 'loop unrolling', for instance.

Answer (score 3):

### Code size

Regarding code size, I put the first implementation into file `f1.c` and the second into `f2.c`.

```
$ gcc -c f1.c f2.c
$ size f1.o f2.o
__TEXT  __DATA  __OBJC  others  dec hex
123 0   0   0   123 7b  f1.o
119 0   0   0   119 77  f2.o
$ gcc -O3 -c f1.c f2.c
$ size f1.o f2.o
__TEXT  __DATA  __OBJC  others  dec hex
372 0   0   0   372 174 f1.o
362 0   0   0   362 16a f2.o
$
```

Note that there is very little difference in the code size for either implementation.  Intriguingly though, the optimized code is a lot bigger (about three times as big) as the unoptimized code.

(Compiler: GCC 4.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.5.)

You should note that the factorials (which is what these functions implement) grow very fast.  In fact, 13! is too big to fit into a 32-bit unsigned integer, 21! is too big to fit into a 64-bit unsigned integer, and 35! is too big to fit into a 128-bit unsigned integer (if you can find a computer with such a type).

---

### Code speed — a contrarian finding!

Also, beware assumptions.  I expected the iterative solution to be faster than the recursive solution.  However, measurement suggests otherwise.

The tests were run on a MacBook Pro with 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 (and 16 GiB memory, but memory isn't a factor in this calculation).

Measurement shows that when the code is optimized, the recursive solution is consistently a little faster than the pure iterative solution, which is absolutely contrary to what I expected, but shows why performance measurements are necessary.

#### Optimized code

```
# iteration
# Count    = 10
# Mean     =   0.799869
# Variance =   0.000011

# recursion
# Count    = 10
# Mean     =   0.750904
# Variance =   0.000014
```

I later added a lookup table function and the times for that were:

```
# lookuptab
# Count    = 10
# Mean     =   0.213836
# Variance =   0.000004
```

And I added a function that simply returned its input parameter to measure the test harness overhead, and that gave:

```
# over-head
# Count    = 10
# Mean     =   0.211325
# Variance =   0.000001
```

So the computational cost of the array lookup is very small.

#### Unoptimized code

If you ever doubted the power of the optimizer, then compare the optimized times with these, for the unoptimized build.

```
# iteration
# Count    = 10
# Mean     =   1.852833
# Variance =   0.000020

# recursion
# Count    = 10
# Mean     =   2.937954
# Variance =   0.000059
```

And the lookup table version:

```
# lookuptab
# Count    = 10
# Mean     =   0.730275
# Variance =   0.000026
```

And the overhead version:

```
# over-head
# Count    = 10
# Mean     =   0.633132
# Variance =   0.000009
```

### General Observations

- Simple 'lines of code' is not sufficient to tell you anything about performance.
- Measurement trumps guesswork.
- Optimizers are good.

The reason why simply counting lines of code is not a good guideline is that different lines have different costs.  For example, a single line of code containing calls to functions like `sin()`, `cos()` and `tan()` will (probably) be vastly more expensive than 20 lines of code containing single integer arithmetic operations and assignments.

When comparing two very similar functions — as in the question — then more complex recursion tends to be slower than simple iteration.  But, as demonstrated, such guessed results can be wrong when the compiler manages to optimize, especially for a simple tail-recursive function such as factorials.

---

### Timing details

Here's a test program:

```
static int fun1(int num)
{
    if (num == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return num * fun1(num - 1);
}

static int fun2(int num)
{
    int i=1;
    do{
        i = i * num;
        num--;
    } while (num);
    return i;
}

static int fun3(int num)
{
    static const int factorial[] =
    {   1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320,
        362880, 3628800, 39916800, 479001600,
    };
    enum { MAX_FACTORIAL_NUM = (sizeof(factorial)/sizeof(factorial[0])) };
    if (num < 0 || num >= MAX_FACTORIAL_NUM)
        return 0;
    else
        return factorial[num];
}

static int fun4(int num)
{
    return num;
}

#include "timer.h"
#include <stdio.h>

static void tester(char const *name, int (*function)(int))
{
    char buffer[32];
    Clock  clk;
    unsigned long long sumfact = 0;

    clk_init(&clk);
    clk_start(&clk);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        sumfact += (*function)(i % 12 + 1);
    clk_stop(&clk);
    printf("%s: %s (%llu)\n", name, clk_elapsed_us(&clk, buffer, sizeof(buffer)), sumfact);
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        tester("recursion", fun1);
        tester("iteration", fun2);
        tester("lookuptab", fun3);
        tester("over-head", fun4);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

The test code is careful to treat the two functions as symmetrically as possible, and alternately tests each function to reduce the chance of background processes interfering with performance.  (The BOINC processes normally running in the background were turned off for these tests; experience with timing for previous questions shows they seriously affect the results and introduce much more variability into the results.)

#### Raw times for optimized (`-O3`) build

Early version of program without lookup table or over-head functions.

```
recursion: 0.754428 (4357969100681262)
iteration: 0.799330 (4357969100681262)
recursion: 0.749773 (4357969100681262)
iteration: 0.798897 (4357969100681262)
recursion: 0.747794 (4357969100681262)
iteration: 0.800977 (4357969100681262)
recursion: 0.748282 (4357969100681262)
iteration: 0.792708 (4357969100681262)
recursion: 0.748342 (4357969100681262)
iteration: 0.798776 (4357969100681262)
recursion: 0.748377 (4357969100681262)
iteration: 0.801641 (4357969100681262)
recursion: 0.750115 (4357969100681262)
iteration: 0.802468 (4357969100681262)
recursion: 0.750807 (4357969100681262)
iteration: 0.802829 (4357969100681262)
recursion: 0.751296 (4357969100681262)
iteration: 0.796841 (4357969100681262)
recursion: 0.759823 (4357969100681262)
iteration: 0.804221 (4357969100681262)

real        0m15.575s
user        0m15.556s
sys         0m0.027s
```

#### Raw times for unoptimized build

Early version of program without lookup table or over-head functions.

```
recursion: 2.951282 (4357969100681262)
iteration: 1.852239 (4357969100681262)
recursion: 2.932758 (4357969100681262)
iteration: 1.851512 (4357969100681262)
recursion: 2.924796 (4357969100681262)
iteration: 1.862686 (4357969100681262)
recursion: 2.946792 (4357969100681262)
iteration: 1.846961 (4357969100681262)
recursion: 2.941705 (4357969100681262)
iteration: 1.849099 (4357969100681262)
recursion: 2.938599 (4357969100681262)
iteration: 1.852089 (4357969100681262)
recursion: 2.930713 (4357969100681262)
iteration: 1.854765 (4357969100681262)
recursion: 2.935669 (4357969100681262)
iteration: 1.851478 (4357969100681262)
recursion: 2.938975 (4357969100681262)
iteration: 1.856979 (4357969100681262)
recursion: 2.938250 (4357969100681262)
iteration: 1.850521 (4357969100681262)

real        0m47.980s
user        0m47.939s
sys         0m0.041s
```

I note that there's a bug in the code of both the factorial functions; both go into long-running loops (and invoke all sorts of undefined behaviour by overflowing the 32-bit `int` type) when asked to calculate 0!, which is actually well defined and has the value 1.  That's why the invocation in the test harness is `(*function)(i % 12 + 1)` rather than `(*function)(i % 13)` as I originally wrote.

Answer (score 2):

(1) uses recursion, and potentially is a subject of stack overflow. (2) is iterative, and uses constant amount of memory. I'd say (2) should be faster .

If you look on disassembled code, (1) will have `call` instruction which is more expensive than just incrementing/decrementing loop counter. However, I believe if you pass 1 as an argument to the function, (1) will probably be faster. If argument is greater than 1, (2) should be executed faster.

Answer (score 0):

A loop is simpler than a function call, speaking about when it get compiled to assembly.

You can measure time taken and memory usage by measuring and comparing of time stamps and memory usage, before and after a piece of code is called.

Answer (score 0):

Iterative (the 2nd one without recursion) is faster.

Check this article with a performance analysis: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21194/Iterative-vs-Recursive-Approaches

Answer (score 0):

The reason one uses more memory is that one eats up space as it recurses to solve the problem.  The problem isn't the recursion, per se, as recursion can be implemented to not use stack space (at least in certain languages where you can use "tail" recursion without penalty).  As written, though, it's not tail recursive, the results of the recursive invocation need to be multiplied with the `num` of the active invocation (this could be written a lot better, sorry).